# How to solve "non-fixed bound or weight" using PYOMO and couenne for a Portfolio Optimization problem

Tags: pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to implement the mean-variance cardinality constrained portfolio optimization (MVCCPO) problem in PYOMO to then solve with the MINLP solver couenne.

The MVCCPO is based on the traditional portfolio optimisation problem (markowitz's original mean-variance model) but with the addition of two more constraints : 1) the cardinality constraint and 2) the floor and ceiling constraints. See http://www.jhumanities.net/article_86973_2cc8b3b4209b171bd61268833c04ee07.pdf for an example of it's use; It is formulated mathematically on page 2(i would write it in here but unfortunately but due to limitations imposed by stackoverflow i am unable)

When i try to run the solve the MVCCPO problem i am met with the error "non-fixed bound or weight". This problem is coming from the following constraint :

l_{i}*\delta_{i}<=w_{i}<=u_{i}*\delta_{i}

where l_{i} and u_{i} is the lower bound and upper bound to invest in stock i: the floor and ceiling constraint. \delta_{i} is the cardinality constraint and is 0 when stock is to not be invested in and 1 if it is to be invested in. w_{i} is the amount of the portfolio invested in stock i.

Here is how the constraint is currently implemented in PYOMO

```
    def floor_ceiling_and_cardinality_constraint(self, m, i):
    return inequality((m.delta[i]*self.l[i]), m.x[i], (m.delta[i] * self.u[i]))
```

How does one implement such a constraint ? I know the constraint mentioned is the one at fault as by removing the cardinality portion of the constraint (\delta_[i]) it works perfectly. I would be forever in debt to the kind soul who can help me at all.

Comment: Hello. I was wondering if someone could tell me what's wrong with this post so that I can edit and improve it? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is a convex problem, so using Couenne is a bit overkill. Couenne is a global solver designed to deal with non-convex problems. High-performance convex MIQP solvers are readily available.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen doesn't the addition of the cardinality constraint cause the problem to be non-convex ? This assumption is based on the following lines from the paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6191315 :"QP
can be used to solve it[portfolio optimisation without cardinality constraint] in an exact manner. However, when
cardinality constraints are imposed, no exact method exists for
solving it."

Comment: No, mean-variance problems with cardinality-constraints are MIQP problems with a convex objective. I.e. all relaxations are convex (apart from slight numerical issues). I typically recommend high-performance convex MIQP solvers for this (e.g. Cplex, Gurobi). These are exact methods (no approximation). I don't know that paper, may be they mean the efficient frontier is not convex (the title indicates they want to explore multiple objectives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sandwich constraint like

```
l(i)*δ(i) ≤ x(i) ≤ u(i)*δ(i)
```

should in general be implemented as two constraints:

```
l(i)*δ(i) ≤ x(i) 
x(i) ≤ u(i)*δ(i)
```

These are now straightforward linear constraints.

Note: Pyomo supports constraints of the form

```
l(i) ≤ expression ≤ u(i)
```

directly (see [link](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyomo_modeling_components/Constraints.html)). But in your case you have variables on both sides.